# Create Workflow Reminder 3 months, 2 months, 1 months befor due date

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

i want to ask how to create workflow reminder on sharepoint 2013.
the workflow with 3 stage (3 months, 2 months, 1 months before due date). could you give me a references for create the reminder?

thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

For doing this the simplest approach is to create a second workflow to the task list(where your list creates all its tasks). This secondary workflow which will run on the task list will run whenever a new item is created in the task list. We can pause it in accordance to the due date. That is :

Lets **assume** that your due date is kept as 4 months from the task creation, so

1. First pause it for 1 month from the task creation date, you can( due data - 90 days) and then send a reminder mail.
2. Then pause it for another 30 days (that happens to be now due data - 60 days), keeping a check if the task is yet not completed and then again send reminder mail.
3. Finally pause it for another 30 days ( that happens to be now due data - 30 days ), keeping a check if the task is yet not completed and then again send reminder mail.

Build a similar logic for the secondary workflow which covers your needs.

You can follow [this](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Create-a-secondary-workflow-6b77ffd5-9ad6-4c20-b5a4-d686e2deafc2?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE) invaluable blog from Microsoft for reference.

Please mark the answer if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

hi all,

i tried to create reminder workflow for -30 days, i stuck to create the 3 trigger for 3 months, 2 months and 1 months.

thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Leverage Information Management Policy.  Create a workflow that only sends the email and then stops.  Use IMP to trigger on a date column to start the notification workflow.  You can set up multiple levels of IMP for your monthly notifications.  Each item will walk through each stage of your IMP.

[Not my blog](https://wardpeter.com/how-to-trigger-a-workflow-on-a-timer-basis-information-management-policies/)

Answer (score -1):

Create the workflow on the list - Add step "Pause until " ... and set date as Due Date - 3 months. Similar for 2 and 1 month.

Once the workflow execution have started, then it will wait for date to be equal to due date - 3 months, once the date is reached mail/ necessary action will be taken. Then similarly add "Pause until .. due date -2 month".